# Does Git scale the same way if I use branches instead of revisions?

Tags: git, version-control, scalability

I want to use Git to store and version data efficiently, but I also want to be able to change revisions on demand.

So I want to use Git with many branches instead of the usual revisions. For every "version" of my data there will be a branch.

Only a few files will change per branch and there would be 1-10 revisions per branch, depending on how often a certain revision has to change.

So the file/data load would be almost normal, I would only have a lot of branches instead of revisions.

I know that this is a strange way to use Git, but would it scale?

dbyrne asked for the usecase. I am not sure if helps, but here it is:

- I plan to version [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) metadata
- I have some project in a separate SCM (e.g. SVN) and every revision belongs to a Vagrant VM
- Every Vagrant VM has metadata and install files, which will often be the same for many revisions
- Sometimes I have to change the metadata and I need to support branches of my project, so I wanted to use Git branches for every revision
- My application will keep track of project revisions and Git metadata
- My application will check out the relevant files for every given project version
- With the metadata it is possible to aromatically create a VM for every project revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, git handles branching very efficiently.  You can switch back and forth between branches very quickly, and they have a small footprint because each branch only stores the delta (not an entire copy).

How many branches are you planning to have?  I think a little more background about your use case might be helpful in answering this question.

Comment: I am not sure if the usecase helps but I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but from my understanding Git works by detailing the changes in each branch so each branch is not a copy of the Trunk or another branch, it simply the details of the differences, so in your example each branch would be very small in terms of data.

I have always been told that Git is designed for high branch usage (it's main selling point IMO) so yes it should scale.

HTH

Paul

Answer (score 0):

What you're after here isn't really a deviation from normal git usage. Branches are useful for holding different variations on the content that you want to track separately, while each branch also contains historical edits going back through time.

Unlike other (usually centralized) vcs packages, git encourages and empowers you to design workflows that fit your specific needs. You have to adapt to SVN. You can mold git around your own processes and needs.

I suspect you'll find the most handy workflow will be to have a central "master" branch where universal changes happen, and then individual branches that are periodically updated from the master. That way you can push big fundamental bugfixes or whatever through all your child branches, while maintaining whatever's unique about each of them.